# How to access map?

Tags: c++, dictionary

I am not sure how to access the map inside the struct Student
Some examples that I look up says -> first ->second
but this does not compile.

How I can access map inside the struct?
or the overloading of the operator is wrong?

the error says  `‘->’ has non-pointer type`

```
struct Student{
      string id;
      map<string, double> scores;
    };


ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Student& g){
    return os << g.id << '\n' <<  g.scores->first << '\n' << g.scores->second ;
}

istream& operator >>(istream& is, Student& g){
    return is >> g.id >> g.scores->first >> g.scores->second;
}


int main() {

    vector<Student> g_vec;
    Student grades;

    while(cin >> gd)
        g_vec.push_back(grades);

    for (auto& g : g_vec)
        cout << g << endl;

    }
```

Comment: You need to use an iterator, method such as `find` or `[]` to access an element of your map it's unclear what you're trying to do here. I think what you want is something like `for (auto& it : g.scores) cout << it->first << it->second;` in your `ostream` and `istream` methods

Comment: @EdChum sorry if its unclear, basically what I am trying to do is overload the operator>> and << save and output data inside the struct directly, my only problem is I don't know how to access map STL .. I know if its a pair you can just use .first and .second, but not sure about map.

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between `.` and `->`is the type of objet you have at the beginning. Use `.`when you have your object, and `->`when you have a pointer to your object

If you define a Student this way

`Student erik = ...`

You'll get erik's id like this :

`erik.id`

If you define erik like this :

`Student* erik = ...`

you'll get his id like this :

`erik->id`

And that's what the error mean

But you have another problem, since `first`and `second`are not defined for a map, but for a map **element**. You'll need to iterate through the map in order to do what you want. I'd guess something like this would be better

```
os << g.id << '\n'
for (auto& it : g.scores) {
    os<< it.first << it.second << '\n' ;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, however I tried the code that you give but the error still there. or maybe I type is wrong this is how I type it  `ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Grades& g){
 os << g.id << '\n';
    for (auto& it : g.scores) {
  os << it->first << it->second << '\n' ;
 }
 
 return os;
}`

Comment: Edited, shame on me, replacing `->` with `.` fixes it. Your code has other problems though, `gd` is undefined for instance.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't understood the problem. It's more elaborate if you show us the sample output.
sorry if I am wrong, I am unable to find when you are going to stop reading data. . ?

You need to use pair to insert to map and to traverse you should use iterator. Hope this helps:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Student& g){
      //here you need to write for loop to traverse the entire map. I am printing only last ele. .  
    map<string,double>::const_iterator myit = g.scores.end();
    os << g.id << '\n' <<  myit->first << '\n' << myit->second ;
    return os;
}

istream& operator >>(istream& is, Student& g){
    pair<string,double> mypair;
    is >> g.id >> mypair.first >> mypair.second;
    g.scores.insert(mypair);
    return is;
}
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the unclear explanation of my problem.. but I am trying to do is overload the operator>> and << to save it to struct but not quite sure how to access map..However this solution almost work I guess but there is an error in this line  `map<string,double>::const_iterator myit = g.scores.end();` it says `conversion error to non-scalar type` but it I change it to auto, the file compile.